# How to start up Gparted? (to partition hard drive)

Tags: partitioning, gparted

How can Gparted be used?

I went to download

```
Stable releases of GParted Live
```

at

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/

for the 0.4.6-1 version.
```

After the .iso image is downloaded, I burned it onto a DVD-R.

Then the DVD-R is booted.  It let me choose something about the keyboard and then showed several icons on top of the screen:

```
Power Down, Screenshot, Terminal, GParted, Info, Screen Resolution
```

but **double clicking on GParted has no response at all**.

Clicking on Terminal brings out a shell but are we supposed to do any "yum" or "apt-get" there?  Isn't the partition app already included?  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is included and will start automatically, it needs to analyze your current partitioning scheme. Patience is the key!

Comment: is that right?  since there is no hourglass or activity monitor or a percent bar, it looks like it is idle... by the way, the C: isn't moving at all... is it running if that's the case?

Comment: I have been waiting 5 minutes now and it is not showing anything... the C: drive light isn't blinking...

Comment: Try Ubuntu, maybe gparted liveCD doesn't have specific drivers for your SCSI device.

Comment: hm... mine is a Dell Inspiron 530 with 700GB hard drive...  should be a fairly basic system.  So Ubuntu installation disc has a partition tool and can repartition and then not install Ubuntu?

Comment: using this DVD-R on both of my other HP computers can lead to GParted running automatically...  it is just the Dell having the problem...

Comment: As LiraNuna said: it's possible that the gparted livecd doesn't have the drivers for your Dell machine. My guess: there's something non-free about your setup and the ubuntu firmware has it where the vanilla kernel does not. Alternately, support was added in a kernel version later than the one used by the livecd.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with bootable DVD-R's running correctly on some systems, particulary with older IDE Combo drives.

One alternative is burn it to CD-R instead of DVD-R.

Another alternative is booting SysRescueCD. The default boot has GParted GUI launchable from the desktop.